# How can I use the loop in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE repeat()
BEGIN
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
     WHILE (i <= 100) DO
        INSERT INTO VISITS VALUES ("C9YAoq", "2022-05-03 00:00:00");
        SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

**The error**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE repeat()
BEGIN
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    ' at line 1
```

I'm trying to insert 100 rows inside the table using the loop but that does not work.

Comment: Is there any reason you want 100 identical rows? Sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `REPEAT` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. If you want to use it for userland names, you should quote it or rather use another name.
2. Use `$$` delimiter to properly mark the end of `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

The result:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `repeat`()
BEGIN
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
     WHILE (i <= 100) DO
        INSERT INTO VISITS VALUES ("C9YAoq", "2022-05-03 00:00:00");
        SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How to call repeat?

Comment: @luq891 You can use `repeat1`, `my_repeat` or whatever you want. :-)

Comment: Still not insert the rows inside the table

Comment: @luq891 Try to specify columns in `INSERT` statement: `INSERT INTO visits (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)`. You should also call the procedure with `CALL my_repeat()`.

Comment: Same, I think the problem with your code won't work.

Comment: Try here and share the result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5

Comment: @luq891 I needed to use different fiddle, because dbfiddle.uk didn't support changing delimiter.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hfaqSdLPGNKyhZtMYuWdzM/0